# Returning a private function pointer in Battleship game c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, private

Happy Saturday!

I am trying to teach myself C++ so I am doing a Battleship program.

This version is fairly standard. The player enters the coordinates of a cell to try to hit a ship. The program stating if a ship is hit. If all cells occupied by a ship are hit, the program prints a message stating that that ship is sunk. After each attempt, the program prints the current state by showing the board with all successful attempts marked by `"*"` or `"x"`respectively.

So I have a board like this for the Battleships

```
   a b c d e f g h i j
  +-------------------+
 0|                   |
 1|                   |
 2|                   |
 3|                   |
 4|                   |
 5|                   |
 6|                   |
 7|                   |
 8|                   |
 9|                   |
  +-------------------+
```

This is my **header file** for context :

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#include "Ship.h"
#include <vector>
class Board
{
  public:
    Board(void);
    void addShip(char type, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    void print(void);
    void hit(char c, int i);
    int level(void);
  private:
    std::vector<Ship *> shipList;
    char score[10][10];
    Ship *shipAt(int x, int y);
};
#endif
```

Here is what I have so far for my CPP (sorry for the long bits of code but it is necessary to provide context for this question:

```
#include "Board.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdexcept>


//member function definitions


Board::Board()
{
    //char score[10][10] = "                                                                                                    ";  
    char score[10][10] = {' '};
}

void Board::addShip(char type, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    if(shipList.size()<=9)
    {
        shipList.push_back(Ship::makeShip((char) type, (int) x1, (int) y1, (int) x2, (int) y2));
    }
}

void Board::print(void){



    cout<< "   a b c d e f g h i j"<< endl;
    cout <<"  +-------------------+"<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout<<" "<< i <<"|" ;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
           cout << score[i][j];
        }
            if(i == 0){
                cout << "                  |";

            }
            else{
                cout << "                   |";
                }
        cout<< endl;

    }
    cout <<"  +-------------------+"<< endl;




}

void Board::hit(char c, int i){

    if (c<'a' || c>'j' || i > 9 || i<0){
        throw invalid_argument("Error: invalid input");
    }


    if (c == 'a'){
        int a = 0;
    }
    if (c == 'b'){
        int b = 1;
    }
    if (c == 'c'){
        int c = 2;
    }
    if (c == 'd'){
        int d = 3;
    }
    if (c == 'e'){
        int e = 4;
    }
    if (c == 'f'){
        int f = 5;
    }
    if (c == 'g'){
        int g = 6;
    }
    if (c == 'h'){
        int h = 7;
    }
    if (c == 'i'){
        int i = 8;
    }
    if (c == 'j'){
        int j = 9;
    }







}
```

For `Ship *shipAt(int x, int y)`
If a ship occupies the cell (x,y) this function returns a pointer to that ship. Otherwise it returns a null pointer.
 `vector<Ship *> shipList` is 
A vector of base pointers to store pointers to the ships

And for `void hit(char c, int i)`
This function is called when the player attempts to hit a cell defined by char c and int i.
The function must determine if a ship is hit and update the ship's level and board status accordingly. It uses the private function shipAt.

Essentially I do not know how I would implement `void hit(char c, int i)` with the private member function  `Ship *shipAt(int x, int y)` and fulfill these requirements.

Comment: I am having a hard time following you, and where you are stuck. Are you stuck at implementing `shipAt`?

Comment: yes I am stuck fulfilling the void hit function and shipAt

Comment: `print` and `shipAt` could probably be `const` member functions, meaning they don't change the `Board`: `void print() const;` and `Ship *shipAt(int x, int y) const;`

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract ASCII letters that are both lowercase or both uppercase (and it will work even on compilers that don't use ASCII).  So I think you just want:

```
void Board::hit(char c, int i){

    if (c<'a' || c>'j' || i > 9 || i<0){
        throw invalid_argument("Error: invalid input");
    }

    Ship* ship = shipAt(i, c-'a');
    if (ship) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
```

}

Comment: So in this case would char a correspond to 0, char b correspond to 1...etc

Comment: Yes, `'a'-'a'` is 0, `'b'-'a'` is 1, ... `'j'-'a'` is 9.

Comment: Thanks! That makes so much sense! but how would shipAt function be defined to return a pointer to the ship. I am asking because I am getting this error.                                     `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Board::shipAt(int, int)", referenced from:
      Board::hit(char, int) in Board-a45c1e.o `

Comment: That error means you either haven't defined `Board::shipAt`, or haven't linked the object file that contains the definition.